# What permissions are needed for user to create Tenant in Opensearch?

Tags: kibana, multi-tenant, opensearch, elasticsearch-opendistro, opensearch-security-plugin

I am trying to create an internal user in Opensearch who can create and delete Tenant

I want to know what permissions I need to assign to internal user to create/delete tenant. I tried giving all_access but I don't want to assign all the access to user.

Answer (score 1):

I think, the following security permission could be helpful:

> restapi:admin/tenants

I found this permission on the following permissions page in OpenSearch's Documentation:

https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/security/access-control/permissions/